# Multiprocessing with python and BaseProcess class

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to launch a function in another process with python, like this :

```
from multiprocessing.process import BaseProcess
import os

class MyProcess(BaseProcess):
    def __init__(self):
        self._identity = ()
        self._name = 'ProcessController'
        self._parent_pid = os.getpid()
        self._popen = None

    def run(self):
        print("Launching foo..." + str(os.getpid()))
        Foo()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("pid : " + str(os.getpid()))
    MyProcess().start()
```

But I've got this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "...\Main.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       MyProcess().start()   File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
>       self._popen = self._Popen(self) TypeError: _Popen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

My purpose is of course to have 2 differents pids for the 2 "print". I can't find how to do this, I didn't find Process class from multiprocessing (like I saw in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html)). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just subclass `Process` directly, and also be sure to call its `__init__` in your own `__init__`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, name='ProcessController'):
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def run(self):
        print("Launching foo..." + str(os.getpid()))
        Foo()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("pid : " + str(os.getpid()))
    MyProcess().start()
```

Note I also left out some of the instance variables you were defining that also get defined in `BaseProcess`, since you really shouldn't be overwriting those. I also passed your custom name to `Process.__init__`, since that's the right way to set it, as opposed than directly setting `self._name`.

The reason `Process` was hard to find in the source is that the `multiprocessing` package populates the top-level `multiprocessing` module in kind of an odd way starting with Python 3.4; it ends up coming from `multiprocessing.context`:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> Process
<class 'multiprocessing.context.Process'>
```